# logstash generic output filename

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I'd like to collect the logs of multiple servers on one logstash node. As output I'd like to store one file per server. In the logs, I got a "source_host" field that indicates which server has produced the log.

As output, I'd like to get a bunch of files named by "source_host". The source hosts change frequently, so I'd need a generic configuration

e.g. logs originating from server "foo" should be saved in /logs/foo and logs from server "bar" in /logs/bar

I tried the config like this, but the file gets named "%{source_host}". When using %{host}, the file gets the hostname of the collecting server.

```
output{
  file {
    path => "/tmp/%{source_host}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a sample log and your filters?

Comment: I don't use any filters (not yet).
sample log:
 `{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z","source_host":"foo","message":"testmsg"}`

Answer (score 1):

My configuration:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5544
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

output{
  file {
    path => "/tmp/%{source_host}"
  }
}
```

outputs to a file /tmp/foo with your sample log.

```
echo '{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z", "source_host":"foo","message":"testmsg"}' | nc localhost 5544
```

**EDIT**:
Here are my test results:

```
pancake$ echo '{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z", "source_host":"foo","message":"testmsg"}' | nc localhost 5544
pancake$ cat /tmp/foo
{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z","source_host":"foo","message":"testmsg","port":56716}
pancake$ echo '{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z", "source_host":"bar","message":"testmsg"}' | nc localhost 5544
pancake$ echo '{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z", "source_host":"bar","message":"one more message!"}' | nc localhost 5544
pancake$ cat /tmp/bar
{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z","source_host":"bar","message":"testmsg","port":56717}
{"version":"debug","host":"devel","level":5,"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-09-15T10:41:00.549Z","source_host":"bar","message":"one more message!","port":56718}
```

**EDIT 2**:
Ooh, I just thought of something. You said earlier that you aren't using any filters, right? You need to use a filter of some kind or another, otherwise the field `source_host` won't exist. If you have `codec => json_lines` (because your logs are JSON) in your input block, as I do in my example, it will parse your JSON into key value pairs. If you have no filter or codec, the entire body of the log will be stored in the `message` field, unmodified. Try adding an input codec and see if that helps.

Comment: strange - I will test again on Monday

Comment: didn't work that way but I got it working using pipe output and a small bash script. Positive side effect: logs without source host set don't get lost

Comment: Hmm, I'm curious about why it didn't work. Which version of Logstash are you on? I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: Check out my edit and let me know if you're using a codec or filter now.

Comment: maybe, I was a bit confusing: the input log is in gelf format. Since it's generated by the application and passed via message queue, I pasted the json-output of logstash when logging to file. I still use no codec or filter at all. I use logstash 2.4. Thank you for looking at it. The bash script version runs fine for now.